# Improve performance of app layout

Tags: android, performance

I am using hierarchy view for check my application layout performance.I reduced most of the things but how to improve frame layout performance so application will be fast.because I am looking red color on frame layout.

How to solve the problem

Here is the XML layout

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/com.org.AmarUjala.news"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
     >


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/header_height"
         >

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/headerView_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/viewpager_height" />

        <com.org.AmarUjala.news.utility.CirclePageIndicator
            android:id="@+id/indicator"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:theme="@style/StyledIndicators"/>

        <com.org.AmarUjala.news.PagerSlidingTabStrip
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/tab_height"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:should_expand="true" />
    </FrameLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: There is no issue in the `FrameLayout` here. The performance issue is probably in one of the items inside it.

Comment: Thanks StenSoft ,but how can solve this issue because I am not getting where is the performance overhead problem.